# Error during DynaLoader.pm execution How does .so file relate or created to this

Tags: perl

I am getting the below error when trying to run a perl script.

```
Can't load '/oatss/oatss-prod/lib/WatchDogErrs.so' for module WatchDogErrs: /oatss/oatss-prod/lib/WatchDogErrs.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 200.
```

How does this .so file get created from .pm file, where is the issue residing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.so` doesn't get created from a `.pm` file, it gets created from a `.xs` file during the Perl module build process (e.g. the `make` after `perl Makefile.PL`).  It's a library of C code integrated into Perl.  Such libraries are architecture and Perl major version-specific.

DynaLoader.pm is one of the 2 main modules for loading C code into Perl (XSLoader.pm is the other).

In this case, it appears somebody compiled WatchDogErrs with a 32-bit Perl and installed it in `/oatss/oatss-prod/lib/`.  You're trying to use it with a 64-bit Perl.  That won't work.  You'll need to use a 32-bit Perl compatible with the one used to compile WatchDogErrs.so, or recompile it with the Perl you want to use (and install it somewhere else, or you'll break the scripts that are using 32-bit Perl).

Comment: As per your suggestion if I had to recompile, I have only WatchDogErrs.pm and a WatchDogErrs.so when given a locate on that file.
So how does a .pm file give a .so file

Comment: As I said, it doesn't.  Someone used `WatchDogErrs.xs` to create the `WatchDogErrs.so` that's on your machine, but didn't leave it there.  Or maybe they built a package on some other machine and just installed that.  Either way, you'd need to get the full source code for WatchDogErrs, including the `.xs` file, in order to recompile it.  That's not a CPAN module, so I assume it's something your company wrote.